# Selenium Webdriver: wait until text is present on page

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath

I've tried this:

```
driver.wait(function() {
  return driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Vanilla Sky Final Scene')]")))
}, 20000).then(function() {
  console.log('worked')
})
```

and this:

```
driver.wait(function() {
  return driver.isElementPresent(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Vanilla Sky Final Scene')]")))
}, 20000).then(function() {
  console.log('worked')
})
```

And this:

```
driver.wait(function() {
  return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Vanilla Sky Final Scene')]")))
}, 20000).then(function() {
  console.log('worked')
})
```

None of them seem to work. What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct function is `isDisplayed()`, the following should work:

```
driver.wait(function() {
  return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Vanilla Sky Final Scene')]")).isDisplayed();
}, 20000);
```

Comment: I think you mean `isDisplayed()` - I would edit it but I only need to edit one character and SO minimum edit is 6 characters :)